# Baby Rudin Definition 2.18

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This are few Definitions stated in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin:

[image]
Now, Consider the interval (1,2).

This interval is closed because according to $(b)$ the every point of this set contains another point in its neighbourhood, thus a limit point, hence closed.

Open at the same time according to the $(e), (f)$ given in the definition.

Please clarify.

Comment: Please do not delete questions after having gotten an answer.

Comment: There is no problem in itself with a set being open *and* closed. That can actually happen too.

Comment: ... also, sets can be open and closed at the same time.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform can you please give one example except $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In the metric space $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ with the inherited metric from the reals, $\{2\}$ is open and closed, e.g. $N_1(2) = \{2\}$ so it's open, and $\{2\}$ has no limit points, so it's closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between

> Every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$ . . . . .$(1)$

and

> Every point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$ . . . . . .$(2)$

You have reasoned that $(2)$ is true and concluded that $E$ is closed. But this is incorrect, because you need to check whether $(1)$ is true, since $E$ is defined to be closed if $(1)$ holds.

And indeed, $1$ is a limit point of $E = (1,2)$ but $1 \not\in E$, so $E$ is not closed.

Comment: Should $p$ be in the set $E$ for the definition $(b)$ ?

Comment: @HindShah no, it is not necessary that $p$ should be in the set $E$ in the definition (b). The definition does not assume that $p \in E$.

Comment: @HindShah without additional assumptions in the statement (b), we just assume that “all points and sets are understood to be elements and subsets of $X$”.

Answer (score 3):

$1$ and $2$ are limit points of $E= (1,2)$ but are not points of $E$. So $E$ is not closed.